# get pointer of member function delphi

Tags: delphi, function, pointers, lazarus

Is there some trick how to get pointer of a member function in Lazarus / delphi?
I have this code which won't compile....
 Error is 
in Delphi:
`variable required`
in Lazarus:
`Error: Incompatible types: got "<procedure variable type of function(Byte):LongInt of object;StdCall>" expected "Pointer"`

The code:

```
  TClassA = class
  public
      function ImportantFunc(AParameter: byte): integer; stdcall;
  end;

  TClassB = class
  public
     ObjectA: TClassA;
     ImportantPtr: pointer;
     procedure WorkerFunc;
  end;

  function TClassA.ImportantFunc(AParameter: byte): integer; stdcall;
  begin
     // some important stuff
  end;

  procedure TClassB.WorkerFunc;
  begin
     ImportantPtr := @ObjectA.ImportantFunc; //  <-- ERROR HERE
  end;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A member function cannot be represented by a single pointer. It needs two pointers, one for the instance and one for the code. But that's implementation detail and you just need to use a method type:

```
type
  TImportantFunc = function(AParameter: byte): integer of object; stdcall;
```

You can then assign ImportantFunc to a variable of this type.

Since you are using stdcall I suspect you are trying to use this as a Windows callback. That's not possible for a member function. You need a function with global scope, or a static function.

Comment: why it is not possible? he can define method as `class`-method and pass `TMethod.Code` pointer as callback? or not?

Comment: @David: you are right. I want to use it as callback. But `TClassA` is in fact a `TCollectionItem` (!) So every item must have its own windows callback :( Therefore it is not possible to define it in the global scope. It's awful, but I cannot belive that it is not possible.

Comment: @teran would have to be static rather than class method

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes. interesting question, we have few instances of `TClassA`..  for each instance we want to pass (pointer to this) method as callback. but static method is the same for all instances and it cant access `self` fields and etc. At the same time we want this method to use some data of each separate `TClassA` instance. May be in this case we can use `TRttiMethod` to `CreateImplementation` of method using anonymous function, wich uses fields of instances? (oh,seems my english is not well (: )

Comment: Usually callback functions include parameters that allow state and/or instance information to be transmitted to the callback. Does your callback do this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, callback function has no parameters for instance identification, so "static" is probably not usable. But answer from @Serg could solve the problem. The trick is `@TClassA.ImportantFunc`, now it compiles well! But the full implementation take more time, to see if it realy works. So later I will see if pointer to "method code" is solution for this problem.

Comment: It looks like you didn't understand my answer.

Comment: If the callback has a parameter for user-defined data, you can use that to pass an object pointer around (if the parameter is an integer, just typecast the pointer) and use a static class method as the callback. Otherwise, you have to create a separate thunk instead, where the thunk is the actual callback and calls the real class method internally. Thunks usually require dynamically allocated executable memory and assembly instructions to work effectively (see the source code for the VCL's `MakeObjectInstance()` function as an example - `TWinControl.WndProc()` is called by a thunk).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I tried @Serg solution (`@TClassA.ImportantFunc`), it compiles, but it acts like a static function and it's a deep hack. It's not suitable for my needs. Definning function as type, could work, but as you said, in member function it is not possible use `stdcall`. (I got AV expception). Is there some workaround for that if I cannot use `static` function and also no function with global scope? (it must be a member function of `TCollectionItem` class)

Comment: @Peter Just as I and others already told you, you can't use a member function here because a member function requires an instance. And you function pointer does not cater for that. Remy highlights a technique that could work for you. But you still have not shown us the form of the function pointer. It's very hard to help if you won't give us all the information.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: thank you very much for patience;) I can describe it more preciselly (but maybe in another question, not here). BTW, I found function `MethodToProcedure` in `http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidCB6EA89E2A26008BF99A4F470B2F97CC120AD2DA.aspx`. It looks promising, but don't know how SAFE it is? If it could run safely on all WIN architectures? (maybe it should be rather a new question on SO).

Comment: That won't work for a 64 bit process and it won't work with DEP enabled. The latter is easy enough to fix, the former is harder to fix. This is the thunk technique that Remy talked about.

Answer (score 2):

```
type
  TImportantFunc = function(AParameter: byte): integer of object;stdcall;

  ImportantPtr: TImportantFunc;

procedure TClassB.WorkerFunc;
begin
   ImportantPtr := ObjectA.ImportantFunc; //  <-- OK HERE
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectA.ImportantFunc` is not a memory location, so address operator `@` can't be applied to it - hence compiler error. It is 2 pointers, `@TClassA.ImportantFunc` (method code) and `ObjectA` (Self argument). An answer to your question depends on what you really need - code pointer, Self, both or none.

---

If you need just to scope a function name use static class method

```
TClassA = class
public
 class function ImportantFunc(Instance: TClassA; AParameter: byte): integer;
                                                               stdcall; static;
end;
```