# using SuperObject to call procedure inside a Class

Tags: delphi, superobject

i'm trying to call a procedure within a class using super object, but it won't work, what am i doing wrong here ?

Code sample:

```
program test_rpc;

{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$MODE OBJFPC}{$H+}
{$ELSE}
  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  SysUtils, superobject;

type
  TCC = class(TObject)
  published
    procedure controler_method1(const This, Params: ISuperObject; var Result: ISuperObject);
  end;

procedure TCC.controler_method1(const This, Params: ISuperObject; var Result: ISuperObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  write('action called with params ');
  writeln(Params.AsString);
end;

var
  s: ISuperObject;
  CC: TCC;
begin
  CC := TCC.Create;
  s := TSuperObject.Create;
  s.M['controler.action1'] := CC.MethodAddress('controler_method1');
  try
    s['controler.action1("HHAHAH")'];
  finally
    s := nil;
    writeln('Press enter ...');
    readln;
  end;
end.
```

that will crash, what am i doing wrong here ?

it actually gets to "action called with Params" but fails to show the param...

Comment: I rolled the question back since your edit completely changed it.

Comment: seems to be FPC question rather than Delphi one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super method has signature as follows:

```
TSuperMethod = procedure(const This, Params: ISuperObject;
    var Result: ISuperObject);
```

This means that you cannot use an instance method since an instance method has an incompatible signature. Your method must look like this:

```
procedure sm(const This, Params: ISuperObject; var Result: ISuperObject);
begin
  ....
end;
```

The reason you get a runtime error rather than a compile time error is that you abandoned the type system by using the @ operator. Remove the @ and your program will fail at compile time with an error message that is a terser version of what I said above.

It's one of the great fallacies of Delphi programming that one must use the @ operator to obtain a function pointer. It's a bad habit that you would do well to unlearn.

Comment: Funny thing, I found this and got it to work, 5min before your response lol..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460171/get-pointer-of-member-function-delphi/10460491#10460491

Comment: look at the updated code (i edited the post), that works, can you explain to me why i needed to add class/static ?

Comment: That runs because a static class method has no implicit this pointer. It's a standard single pointer function. Unlike an instance method which is a two pointer function.